# Shortest paths and edge weight transformations

Tags: graph-theory

I have a question regarding shortest paths. Given a graph, any linear transformation in edge weights won't change the actual shortest path, w.r.t. the original graph.

My question is w.r.t. nonlinear transformations in the edge weights. Can the shortest path remain unchanged in this case? Specifically, assuming that all edge weights are greater than zero $e_{ij} > 0$, would the following transformation: $exp(e_{ij}$) change the actual shortest path w.r.t. the original graph?

Tks.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do this if you're allowed to choose the graph and edge weights (and $f$ is continuous, but nonlinear).  If $f$ is a nonlinear function, then there always exist $a$ and $b$ so that $f(a)+f(b)\not=f(a+b)$.  Suppose, additionally, that $f$ is continuous.

- Suppose that $f(a)+f(b)<f(a+b)$.  Consider a triangle with edge lengths $a$, $b$, and $c$ where $c$ is slightly less than $a+b$.  Then the shortest path changes from the $c$-edge to the other two edges.
- Suppose that $f(a)+f(b)>f(a+b)$.  Consider a triangle with edge lengths $a$, $b$, and $c$ where $c$ is slightly greater than $a+b$.  Then the shortest path changes from the $a$ and $b$ edges to the other edge.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!